# How to replace a values present of a url in a text file

Tags: shell, jenkins, find, replaceall, har

I have a har file which consist of lot of http values and site information. my requirement is to find and replace the "http://testing.smart" to "http://staging.smart" in all occurrences of the same file. How to do this in shell ?

```
Example
test.har

Output:
Replace all "http://testing.smart" modified to "http://staging.smart" in test.har

Thanks!!
```

Comment: search here for `[bash] sed substitute` and read 10-20 QA. OR [Sed Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) will get you up-to-speed quickly Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [sed command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)

```
sed -i 's/<regex (or word) to change>/<new word>/g' <file path>
```

Most tutorials or manuals use the slash as delimiter but you can use another character to avoid conflicts. So:

```
sed -i 's#<regex (or word) to change>#<new word>#g' <file path>
```

In your case you would do it like this

```
sed -i 's#http://testing.smart#http://staging.smart#g' test.har
```